# Does GroovyScriptEngine spawn a process

Tags: groovy

I am interested in how internally GroovyScriptEngine works. Does it spawn a process from the parent JVM? If so does it block till the process exits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it runs in the current thread ([as can be seen in the source code](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/groovy/util/GroovyScriptEngine.java#L567))

```
public Object run(String scriptName, Binding binding) throws ResourceException, ScriptException {
    return createScript(scriptName, binding).run();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. I suppose GroovyShell doesn't spawn any threads or processes. Sounds like a good alternative to what I've been doing so far, which is to fork processes that run python or bash scripts from java.